# Github actions Runner listener exited with error code null

Tags: nginx, continuous-integration, github-actions

In my server, if I run

> sudo ./svc.sh status

I got this

[image]

It says status is active. But **Runner listener exited with error code null**

In my, Github accounts actions page runner is **offline**.
The runner should be **Idle** as far as I know.

This is my workflow

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 12.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
```

Here I don't have any build scripts because I directly push the build folder to Github repo.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue and it turned out to be a disk space problem. Make sure your server has enough allocated storage.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue when I first installed the runner application under `$USER1` but configured it as a service when I was `$USER2`.

In the end, I ran  `cd /home/$USER1/actions-runner && sudo ./svc.sh uninstall` to remove the service.

Changed the owner of the all files in the `/home/$USER1/actions-runner/` by
`sudo chown -R $USER2 /home/$USER1/actions-runner`.

And ran `./config.sh remove --token $HASHNUBER` (you can get this by following this [page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/removing-self-hosted-runners)) to removed all the runner application.

I also removed it from github settings runner page.

In the end, I installed eveything again as the same user, and it worked out.